# how to get image from gallery with itemview OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

//
    }
});
```

Now, it is impossible to use startActivityForResult.

I have to use a launcher, but I don't know what to do because it's a click event that happens in the item view and I'm going to put the image in the item view

I tried various methods, but they were all for activities, so they didn't work.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Answer (score 0):

You need either to cast the context to Activity, or to pass the onClickListener to the adapter as following

1. Create the clickListener

   ```
   public interface MyClickListener {
       void onItemClick(MyModel model);
   }
   ```
2. In your adapter class:

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
     private MyClickListener onClickListener;
     public MyAdapter(MyClickListener onClickListener) {
         this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
3. In your method:

   ```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onClickListener.onItemClick(myModel);
        }
    });
   ```
4. In your activity:

   ```
   MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(new MyClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(MyModel model) {
               /// here you can call startActivityForResult
        }
   });
   ```